# PYTHON FB API , get token to check public post condivision

Tags: python-2.7, facebook-graph-api, token

i am lookin for check te sharing of a page, for examples bill gates post:

```
page = '10152525603066961'
token = '***'

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
profile = graph.get_object(page)

posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'sharedposts')

print posts['data'][0]['from']
```

it works with the graph access Token, but it will expire and it don't work with App Token.
how can i get a Token that works and will not expire?

Answer (score 0):

Only App Access Tokens and Extended Page Access Tokens are valid forever. What you need is a User Access Token, you can only extend that one to 60 days.

More information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2

Comment: Can i request a new one from python shell?

Comment: you can't auto-refresh a user token, if that is what you mean.

Comment: i have added another link to the facebook docs about login stuff

Comment: I have read it but there aren't informatin about python coding.. I can t even from server requests?

Comment: no, you can´t login on the server. here´s how to deal with facebook login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2

Comment: i guess you will have a hard time using pyhton, to be honest. better use php on your server, you will get a lot more help. python is rarely used with facebook